# ZABBIX 4.0 Entity Relationship Diagram or Database Schema

Tags: mysql, database, schema, entity, zabbix

Specifically for ZABBIX 4.0, is the Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) or Database Schema available from anybody? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Database_Schemas) is quite outdated, the schema is for the 2.4 version.

However you can use MySQL Workbench to plot it: connect to Zabbix's mysql, then Database -> Reverse Engineer and follow the steps.

Here's a sample from my Zabbix 4.0 server:

[image]