# How to Filter QUERY by HOST - ZABBIX

Tags: postgresql, zabbix

I have the following QUERY for ZABBIX POSTGRES bank:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ( date_trunc('hour', clock) ) value,
                   date_trunc('hour', clock)
    FROM history
WHERE
    date_trunc('day', clock) = current_date
ORDER BY
    date_trunc('hour', clock),
    clock;
```

**HISTORY DATA TABLE**

```
itemid    clock      value        ns
28689   1569375369  63.8116     143133362
28689   1569375399  62.9536     199915638
28689   1569375429  63.1248     268331447
28689   1569375459  63.5433     349290199
28689   1569375489  63.246      423979517
28689   1569375519  63.746      486861983
```

It returns the history table values to me every 1 hour.

My question is, how can I make this query filter the values according to HOST ID or HOSTNAME?

Comment: You should use the `history.get` api for this, not a direct sql query.

Comment: What would this python search with API look like?

Comment: My problem is understanding how zabbix identifies these values for each host!

Comment: api returns same SQL query value pattern -> https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/history/get

Comment: If I remember correcty `history` has an `itemid` which references `items`. `items` has an `hostid` which references `hosts`.

Comment: Well, thank you very much, I took a look at the documentation, Do I need to make an INNER JOIN to fetch this query with a query?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/669f1/2 any suggestion?

Comment: Usually you call `host.get` to get the host id by name, then call `item.get` with the host id and the item name you want, then call `history.get` with the host id, the item id and a time range or a limit etc...

Comment: If you prefer to stick with SQL, you can refer to the schema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978003/zabbix-4-0-entity-relationship-diagram-or-database-schema - that's from a mysql Zabbix, postgres schema *should* be the same,

Comment: Okay, thank you so much Simone, the relational scheme that has gone through, will help a lot !!